# Pandas - ValueError on datetime format mismatch

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

This is my data:

```
date = df['Date']
print (date.head())

0   2015-01-02
1   2015-01-02
2   2015-01-02
3   2015-01-02
4   2015-01-02
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

my code:

```
def date_to_days(date):
    return date2num(datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Why am I getting that error?

Comment: This question seems to be about the panda library as well. Please include that in your question.
What kind of data is date? What happens when you print it? The function strptime requires a string. It is 'dumb' as it does not search for the date part of a string, so strip all unnecessary data from the string you pass to datetime.

Comment: Are you trying to extract the days from the `datetime` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine for me without any errors.

```
In [74]: from matplotlib.dates import date2num

In [75]: df['Number of days'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: date2num(datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d')))

In [76]: df
Out[76]: 
         Date  Number of days
0  2015-01-02        735600.0
1  2015-01-02        735600.0
2  2015-01-02        735600.0
3  2015-01-02        735600.0
4  2015-01-02        735600.0
```

In general, it's a bad practice to assign variables to a pandas series object. It can mess a lot of things up.

```
In [1]: def date_to_days(date):
   ...:     return date2num(datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d'))

In [2]: df['Number of days'] = df['Date'].apply(date_to_days)

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
         Date  Number of days
0  2015-01-02        735600.0
1  2015-01-02        735600.0
2  2015-01-02        735600.0
3  2015-01-02        735600.0
4  2015-01-02        735600.0
```

Comment: I think it's because his representation of the dates is actually hiding the times that are also present...

Comment: Yep. I think that might be the case.